# Even though I have downloaded both Twilio and Client, python cannot import Client

Tags: python, twilio

When trying to run a program it says it cannot import name Client. However, it has already been downloaded and works when I write it out line by line in the command module.

I have already downloaded both Twilio and Client.

from twilio import Client
ImportError: cannot import name Client

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the [Twilio Python helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) you import the `Client` from `twilio.rest`, like this:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
```

Try that and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question. I downloaded python on my mac and used online tutorials to pip install twilio from the terminal. If I input my code line by line into the terminal then it works. However, if I try to run an IDLE document it states I have to install Twilio. How can I get my downloads to transfer across?

Comment: Oh, I'm not the most experienced Python developer and don't have a good explanation myself for installing application level dependencies. I would recommend you take a read through [this article on application dependencies on Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/application-dependencies.html) particularly checking out the bit on isolating dependencies and virtualenv. Hopefully that will help.